# How to navigate to a fragment by clicking on an image in another fragment, using Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments- Home Fragment and Frag 2. I have an image in Home Fragment (id: imageView3), and when I click on the image, I should be taken to Frag 2. I have made the image clickable using the following lines of code:

```
android:id="@+id/imageView3"
android:layout_width="383dp"
android:layout_height="211dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

I am adding the Home Fragment and Frag 2 codes below, I have tried to set On Click in the home fragment, but I am not sure how to ad corresponding code to Frag 2. I have added navigation from Home Fragent to Frag 2, but I think I should also add some code to MainActivity?
All the online reference I came across are very confusing and I am a beginner and trying to learn on my own, so please help me out regarding the code in Home Fragment, Frag 2 and MainActivity. Your help s much appreciated!!

HomeFragment.kt

```
package com.example.landingpages.ui.home

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.landingpages.Frag2
import com.example.landingpages.R
import com.example.landingpages.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val imageView5 = findNavController(R.id.imageView5) as ImageView
        imageView5.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Frag2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
        val textView: TextView = binding.textView
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Frag2.kt

```
package com.example.landingpages

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.landingpages.databinding.FragmentIplAuctionBinding

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class Frag2 : Fragment() {
        private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentIplAuctionBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentIplAuctionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)


        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ipl_auction, container, false)
    }


    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.landingpages

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.landingpages.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
                val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_matches, R.id.navigation_profile
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

I have added setOnClickListener to the home fragment. I think I have to add return () to the Frag 2, but I am not sure. I am also not sure ho to ad Frag 2 to the Main Activity, since the other fragments I use are liked to a navigation bar.
The ask is pretty simple: If user clicks on imageview3, they should be taken to Frag 2

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate) is to navigate to the view during your onClick:

```kotlin
val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToFrag2
imageView5.setOnClickListener { 
  imageview5.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

I recommend taking [this course](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) to fully understand fragment navigation also.

Comment: I don't understand, this has to be done in my first fragment?

Comment: And if yes, nothing has to be added to the Frag 2?

Comment: Yes, the change must be made to your HomeFragment. Navigate is dependent on Fragment names to build methods for actions.

Comment: Ok got it. But the imageView part appears in red for me, am I missing any import?

Comment: Adding imports:
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.startingpages.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

Comment: @MathuramMurugaiyan, `imageView5` was meant to match your existing variable name. Your existing imports should have worked without modification.

Comment: Yes but it is coming in red, not sure of the reason.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you either deleted the import for `ImageView` or you deleted the `val` initialization of the `imageView5` variable.